# Who wrote the message on the stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, synchronic

In the movie [Synchronic](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9016974/) Brianna is sitting down on a stone during a birthday party and there's an inscription carved in the stone that says "All ways" (or "Always", I can't remember).

At the end of the movie, we know it was not written by her because when Steve says he saw her message she replies "What message?"

We see that

> when Steve arrives to rescue Brianna, there's no carving in the stone. Since he stays behind...

So I assumed he carved it, but is there anything in the movie that would imply it was him? Does the writing have any meaning to any of the characters?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that the unique misspelling of the word was meant to indicate that Steve was the one who carved it into the stone. Steve and Dennis remarked in this just before Steve goes back to rescue Brianna.

I might have missed if the writing had any significance, but just assumed that the significance was that it was a Spelling uniquely known to the 3 involved.